# R - Contour Map with multiple layers (lattice)

Tags: r, dictionary, panel, lattice, contour

Here is my code and associated variable structures.

```
Correlation_Plot = contourplot(cor_Warra_SF_SST_JJA, region=TRUE, at=seq(-0.8, 0.8, 0.2), 
labels=FALSE, row.values=(lon_sst), column.values=lat_sst,
xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude')

Correlation_Plot = Correlation_Plot + layer({ ok <- (cor_Warra_SF_SST_JJA>0.6);
            panel.text(cor_Warra_SF_SST_JJA[ok]) })
Correlation_Plot

     # this is the longitude (from -179.5 to 179.5) , 360 data in total
    > str(lon_sst) 
     num [1:360(1d)] -180 -178 -178 -176 -176 ...

     # this is the latitude (from -89.5 to 89.5), 180 data in total 
    > str(lat_sst) 
     num [1:180(1d)] -89.5 -88.5 -87.5 -86.5 -85.5 -84.5 -83.5 -82.5 -81.5 -80.5 ...

     # This is data set corresponding to longitude and latitude  
     > dim(cor_Warra_SF_SST_JJA) 
       [1] 360 180
```

[image]

I tried to use `layer()` to show the label just for contour bigger than 0.6, but it doesn't work.

1. Is it possible to increase the colour contrasts in the legend so it can be really clear what colour responds to what level. What are colour options, i can't find them?
2. The most important is I want to draw a thicker black line for a specified contour interval (e.g. for +/- 0.2)? I think ican do it with `layer()` as well, but i am not sure what `panel` function should i use.
3. Also, i tried to fill in the continent with a solid colour, but i can't find any thing with it.
   I have tried use map, but it doesn't work for lattice.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `?panel.levelplot` for additional arguments to `contourplot`.

1. You can use the `col.regions` argument, which will take either a vector of colours that you'd like to correspond to your intervals, or a color ramp function (e.g. below).
2. Use a custom panel function, something like this (using a spatially autocorrelated dummy dataset generated using a method given on [Santiago Beguería's blog](http://santiago.begueria.es/2010/10/generating-spatially-correlated-random-fields-with-r/)). Use `lpolygon` to plot the map object:

   Generate dummy dataset:

   ```
   library(gstat)

   # create structure
   xy <- expand.grid(1:360, 1:180)
   names(xy) <- c('x','y')

   # define the gstat object (spatial model)
   g.dummy <- gstat(formula=z~1, locations=~x+y, dummy=T, beta=1,    
     model=vgm(psill=0.025,model='Exp',range=5), nmax=20)

   # make a simulations based on the gstat object
   yy <- predict(g.dummy, newdata=xy, nsim=1)
   gridded(yy) = ~x+y

   # scale to range [-1, 1]
   z <- matrix(yy@data[, 1], ncol=180)
   z.scalefac <- (max(z) - min(z)) / 2
   z <- -1 + (z - min(z)) / z.scalefac
   ```
3. Plot:

   ```
   library(lattice)
   library(maps)

   lon_sst <- seq(-179.5, 179.5, 1)
   lat_sst <- seq(-89.5, 89.5, 1)

   colramp <- colorRampPalette(c('red', 'yellow', 'white', 'green', 'blue'))

   contourplot(z, xlim=c(100, 160), ylim=c(-80, -50), 
     at=seq(-1, 1, 0.2), region=TRUE, col.regions=colramp,
     row.values=lon_sst, column.values=lat_sst, labels=FALSE, 
     xlab='longitude', ylab='latitude',
     panel = function(at, region, ...) {
       panel.contourplot(at=at, region=TRUE,  ...)
       panel.contourplot(at=c(-0.2, 0.2), lwd=2, region=FALSE, ...)
       mp <- map("world", "antarctica", plot = FALSE, fill=TRUE)
       lpolygon(mp$x, mp$y, fill=TRUE, col='gray')
   })
   ```

[image: example output]

Comment: In my computer, 'col.regions=colramp' doesn't work, but i replaced with 'color.palette=colorRampPalette(c("blue","green","white","yellow", "red"))'. It really helpful, but how can i fill the continent?

Comment: yes, sorry, I forgot to paste in my ramp... have edited the answer.

Comment: @YuDeng: There are so many good aspects to this answer! Please go back , and checkmark jbaums' answer to your earlier question. We should encourage this kind of effort. I don't need points as much as I need to see great worked examples.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: You will need to use `llines` or `panel.lines` with the same data you used for the continental outlines in the previous question to do that

Q2:

```
?panel.contour
```

.... Wherein it says that "lwd" is an available option and I suspect that you would make the seventh element of a vector = 2.

Q3: Probably a fill argument, but it must be noted that you are seriously inhibiting our efforts at testing solutions by not including a link to the data and your data preparation.

Comment: Sorry abt any incovalence, I just start using R for 2 week, gotta do whole thing from the scratch.  The help page for me is really confusing. Are all the arguments working for both and multiple function and sometime i have no idea what to put aft the arguments.

Comment: The arguments are not at all standardized in R functions. Plus,:  you have three different plotting paradigms:base graphic, lattice (which is what contourplot is part of) and ggplot... a perfect recipe for confusion.

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit tricky when we don't have the data. I've edited my solution to include the generation of the dummy dataset I used.

Comment: at first, i thought for you guys just need set the variable as random numbers, as long as the code works, it would be alright. So next time, what should i include when i ask question?

Comment: @YuDeng  well, in a lot of cases that would be probably be ok, but contour plots don't really make sense unless the data is spatially auto-correlated. It's usually a good idea to use `dput()` so that we can reproduce your data (because your matrix is pretty massive, you could just provide a subset). If you're reluctant to provide your actual data (licensing, etc.), then provide some fake data (or add noise to your, if that's good enough for you).

Comment: @jbaums: I certainly agree that questioners _should_ provide their own data in the form of dput() results or constructing with code, but this did result in you providing that most excellent link to Santiago Beguería's page.